# In angular ng-grid how to specify a count for a sub array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I need to specify a count of x units if a field contains an array of more than one items.  How do I do this in ng-grid field display names?

Json Example:
$scope.data = [{id: {1, 3},
    nm: John Doe}
    ,
    {id: {2,4,5},
    nm: Jane Doe}]

Current result:

```
Id              Name
--------------  -------------------------------
1,3             John Doe
2,4,5           Jane Doe
```

Desired result:

```
Id              Name
--------------  -------------------------------
2 Ids           John Doe
3 Ids           Jane Doe
```

Current Angular code:

```
                $scope.gridOptions = {
                    data: 'data',
                    selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
                    columnDefs: [
                    {field: 'id', displayName: 'Id', width: '***'},
                    {field: 'nm', displayName: 'Name', width: '****'}],
                    multiSelect: false
                };
```

Comment: is id really an object or is it an array: id:[1,3] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a cell template like this:

```
<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>{{row.getProperty("id").length}} Ids</span></div>
```

Then apply it like so:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {


    $scope.myData = [{id: [1, 12], name: 'John Doe'},
                     {id: [3, 7, 9, 6, 2], name: 'John Doe'},
                     {id: [10, 52, 78], name: 'John Doe'},
                     {id: [101, 88, 72, 99], name: 'John Doe'}];


    $scope.columnDefs = [
      {
        displayName:'Id',
        cellTemplate: 'cellTemplate.html'
      },
      {
        field:'name', displayName:'Name'
      }
    ]

    $scope.gridOptions = { 
      data: 'myData',
      columnDefs: $scope.columnDefs 
    };
});
```

**Example:** [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ziVRwm?p=preview)

Comment: I guess I need a function if its only 1 item then show the value.  Can I do that in a function within the template?

Comment: You can use a function outside of the template in the controller. I updated the Plunker to demonstrate.

Comment: Is the column value col.colValue?  or col.colText or something like that?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: I found it, row.getProperty("id") was an array of one or more ids so I had to use row.getProperty("id")[0]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get just the count/length of sub array simply use as bellow

```
{field: 'id.length', displayName: 'Id', width: '***'},
```

if you want to add additional things like, text,Images,Icons..etc you should use a cellTemplate as above answer

thanks